# $3$D delta distribution integral with absolute value function

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, absolute-value, dirac-delta

I want to calculate the following integral (in polar coordinates):
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\delta(|\vec{s}|-R)\frac{\hat{e}_\phi(\vec{s})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|}\mathrm d\vec{s}
$$
but I don't know how to deal with the absolute value term. I don't know how to vary it so that a $|\vec{s}|$ stands alone. Hope you have some tips for me. Or tell me that it isnt integrable :S

PS: $\phi$ is the one that that goes from $0$ to $\pi$. So the one that isn't in the $xy$ plane.

Comment: Introduce polar coordinates. Then the 3D integration variable $s$ becomes $(rsin \theta cos \phi, rsin \theta sin \phi, r cos \theta)$. Substitute this into the absolute value term. Integration over the Delta function has the effect of setting $r$ equal to $R$.

Comment: and do i get and extra $ sin(\phi)r^2$ from the substitution then ? im a little confused because i already got a unit vector of spherical coordinates there

Comment: Yes, the volume element $ds$ becomes $r^2 dr sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$.